# What does char casting in this Java println call do?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming in java and I do not understand a println statement. I can run it but cannot understand what it does. Can anyone explain what this does?

`System.out.println((char) ('a' + 4));`

Comment: Please read on ASCII. http://www.asciitable.com the answer is 101

Answer (score 4):

1. `'a'` is a `char` literal;
2. `char` is an intergral numeric type in Java, just like `int`;
3. `+` occurring between two numeric values means *addition*;
4. `(char)` indicates a *conversion* into a `char` type;
5. a `char`, when printed, renders as the Unicode codepoint it represents.

Comment: Appreciate pointing out that `char` is considered a numeric type. People typically don't emphasize this enough in an explanation and then are confused when `'a' + 'b'` does not return "ab".

Answer (score 2):

That simply prints out the letter `e`.  @wrongAnswer has referenced the ASCII character codes, which is a numbering system that assigns unique IDs to characters.  Take a look at this one for example: http://www.asciitable.com/.

If you take a look at the way the lower case letters are arranged in the table, you'll see that the letter `a` is at 97, `b` is at 98, `c` is at 99 and so on. What the above code is doing is that we are finding what the ASCII code of `a` is, then adding by 4, then casting back to `char`.  Therefore, what this is actually doing is taking `97` then adding with `4`, producing `101`.  If you consult the table, `101` is actually `e`, and so the output is `e` after casting `101` with `char`.

Answer (score 0):

the `ascii` value of `a` is `97` so `97+4=101` `101` which is `ascii` value of alphabets `e`.

```
System.out.println((char) ('a' + 4));
```

so the above sop will print `e`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this down into discrete statements:

```
char a = 'a'; // the character a
int aPlusFour = a + 4; //characters are really an integer value for the ASCII code, so we can add four 
char aPlusFourChar = ((char) aPlusfour); //cast our integer back to a char
System.out.println(aPlusFourChar); //this should print the character e
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 'a' == 97
2. 97+4 == 101
3. (char)101 == 'e'
4. System.out.println('e'+""); // prints 'e'

Answer (score -1):

First a ascii value is added to the value 4. and the character respective to the value 101 is printed..it is 'e'.You can refer ascii table